# How to add header to axios.create in react/redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to access JSON data using axios.create in my react-redux app. I have thunk installed as middleware. I'm getting a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error. 
From what I've read online, I might be able to solve this by adding headers to the axios.create call.
How would I go about doing this?

```
//api file
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://www.thehomelike.com/search/'
})

//actions/index.js
import jsonPlaceholder from '../apis/jsonPlaceholder';

export const fetchPosts = () => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('DE/Berlin?country=DE&east=13.499539418719593&lang=en-GB&lat=52.52000659999999&lng=13.404953999999975&locality=Berlin&mapLimit=24&north=52.5942101138977&south=52.445677542691186&west=13.310368581316283');

    dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response })
  }
}
```

These are the headers according to chrome's network tool.

```
Response Headers:
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: authorization
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.thehomelike.com
date: Mon, 01 Apr 2019 06:23:11 GMT
server: nginx
status: 204
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
x-powered-by: Express
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create axios instance with default header as

```
const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://www.thehomelike.com/search/', 
  headers: { // ...your headers}
});
```

The issue you are facing, it can be solved on `server` side as well. 
You have to update the server policies to allow CORS. If you have your server in `node-express` you can try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Which ones do I include? I included all the response headers at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I think, instead of editing the request, you should modify your server policies

Comment: I don’t have access to the server

Comment: How this code resolves the CORS issue, can someone guide me? @Harish

Comment: @AshishKamble above code do not resolve CORS, it should be handled on your API server only.

Answer (score 0):

Could U try use `Postman` to send request? If `Postman` can send your request, this error come from your server. If you use Express, this code snippet can helper U, however, would enable CORS for all resources on your server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: Postman can send the request, so in there it's pulling up the JSON file.